# Real time plotting in c++

Tags: user-interface, plot, real-time, wxwidgets, imgui

I'm trying to figure out which is the best way to render real time plot in c++ (fast data rate):

1. Retained mode GUI (WxWidgets)
2. Retained mode GUI + OpenGL
3. Immediate mode GUI (Imgui)

Comment: best way in reagards to what? Performance? Coding? Anything else? Also I believe such questions are OT here on SO...

Comment: Regarding performance. I developed the application using QT and now I want to change to WXWidgets or Imgui for license issues.

Comment: what platform? Is data comes in real time? how fast it comes in?

Comment: Linux, 4 channels audio data at 48KHz rendered in different plots: time view of 4 channels, spectrum view of 4 channels, spectrogram view of 1 channel.

Comment: Since there is a flawed slow human at the receiving end here, you only need a soft real-time. Which makes pretty much all the options good enough. Human eye won't detect few millisecond lag or even a few skipped frames. In terms of ease of implementation, OpenGL or Vulcan would have been the easiest to get a soft real-time responsiveness. The higher level GUI frameworks are cranky and will get in your way all the time.

Comment: yes, the plan is to accumulate samples and redraw the plot at 30 or 60 fps

Answer (score 0):

go for imgui.
dear imgui is modern and quite powerful as per my view.

implot can be considered (pre-requisite imgui).